# Scroll bars on a Delphi FMX tComboBox.ListBox not showing on a Mac

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tcombobox

I’m using Delphi 10.4.2 and trying to make the vertical scroll bar on the listbox of an FMX tCombox show all the time.  It works fine on a PC but on a Mac the scrollbar disappears unless you’re actively scrolling the mouse wheel.  If I put a regular tListbox on the form, I can make the vertical scroll bar appear constantly with the line `ListBox1.AniCalculations.AutoShowing:=false;` but I can’t seem to do the same for a tComboBox.Listbox.  Nothing I can think of to try has any affect on the tCombox.ListBox.  There must be some way to make the scroll bar stay; what am I missing?

Comment: I have never used a MAC so this may be rubbish. Perhaps scrollbars are hidden by default. Just found the following system setting that controls this. [Look here](https://www.howtogeek.com/207749/how-to-enable-scroll-bars-in-os-x-to-improve-usability/)

Comment: I’ve read that and played with that setting but found that it doesn’t affect FMX apps, regardless of the option selected.  After Struggling with this for another day I’ve made some interesting discoveries:

Setting a tComboBox.DropDownKind to Custom causes the scroll bars to appear in a TComboBox.

Setting a tMemo.AutoHide property to false causes the scroll bars to appear in that tmemo.

A tComboBox has neither of those settings and I have yet to find some way to cause the scroll bars to appear, so I’m still hunting for a solution in that case.

Comment: @Gregg did you find any solution ?